# What is the expected distance to the nearest molecule?

Tags: probability, expected-value, spatial

You may assume any easy model without collisions/attractions, molecule diameters of 0 and perfect mixing.

If you have 500 copies per micro-m^3 of molecule A , then each  molecule A has a box of 125 nm x 125 nm x 125 nm. However, according to my intuition, the expected distance to the closest neighbor should be significantly less than 125 nm, as the shapes of the theoretical volumes will not be perfectly cubic/spherical.

**So my question is:**

- What is the expected distance between molecules A (to the closest molecule A)?

**Background**
According to [this source](http://book.bionumbers.org/how-many-proteins-are-in-a-cell/), we have 1^6 proteins per micro m^3 in huma cells.
If we assume 20.000 genes and that my protein is ~10x more expressed than average genes (which might not be expressed at all), then this would be 500 copies per micro-m^3.

**EDIT:  Added simulation**

This is a simulation of the distance of the nearest neighbor to the center of a micron cube. The center was named "RNA". This represents N=501 molecules.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a homework, test, or similar self-study question. If so, please read the [information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) on how we handle these questions, and add the `self-study` tag to your question.

Comment: This is  for a paper. I want to compare the expected distance between copies of a certain protein of interest to the distance they assume in presence of an adapter protein.

Comment: If you are looking for references https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_inter-particle_distance#Nearest_neighbor_distribution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider $d$ dimensions.  The distribution to the nearest neighbor of any point can be approximated by supposing $N$ neighbors are independently, uniformly, and randomly situated within a radius of one unit from that point (where the distance unit and $N$ are chosen to reproduce the molecular density; preferably $N$ is large).

The chance that one given neighbor is further than a distance $r$ (for $0\le r \le 1$) is the relative volume of the spherical shell between the balls of radii $r$ and $1,$ equal to

$$S_{d}(r) = 1 - r^d.$$

Since the neighbor positions are independent, the chance that *all* are further than distance $r$ is

$$S_{N;d}(r) = (1-r^d)^N.$$

**This (the survival function) determines the distribution of the distance $R$ to the nearest neighbor.**  Its expectation is the integral of the survival function,

> $$E[R] = \int_0^1 S_{N;d}(r)\,\mathrm{d}r = \int_0^1 (1-r^d)^N\,\mathrm{d}r = B(N+1,1/d)/d$$

where $B$ is the Beta function

$$B(a,b) = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}.$$

For instance, here is a histogram of 50,000 simulated values of $R$ with $N=500-1$ neighbors.

[image: Figure]

On it I have superimposed the graph of the density function $-d/dr\, S_{499;3}(r)$ in red to show the agreement and I have plotted a vertical line to show $E[R].$

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks for this solution! Would the result change, if you did the calculation with different absolute molecule counts at constant concentration?

Comment: That's a good question. You can see that the distribution is concentrated at small values of $R.$ In this range, $(1-r^d)^N$ is closely approximated by $\exp(-Nr^d).$ The argument $Nr^d$ is the expected number of points a distance $r$ away.  Thus, once $N$ exceeds a fairly small value, the distribution essentially stabilizes as a generalized exponential.  I originally thought of making this approximation--which I'm sure countless physicists have done--the availability of a simple exact solution was more appealing.

Comment: Dear @whuber, would the distance of a molecule B to the closest of 500 molecules A, be the same as your simulation of 500 molecules A, but with N= 501?