# Get Continuous Distribution from Discrete Variable: Problem 6.77 of Wackerly, Mendenhall, Schaeffer, 5th Ed

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, density-function, weibull-distribution, function

**Problem Statement:**

$\newcommand{\szdp}[1]{\!\left(#1\right)}$
Let $v$ denote the volume of a three-dimensional figure. Let $Y$
denote the number of particles observed in volume $v,$ and assume that $Y$ has
a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda v.$ The particles might represent
pollution particles in air, bacteria in water, or stars in the heavens.

If a point is chosen at random within the volume $v,$ show that the
distance $R$ to the nearest particle has the probability density function
given by
$$f(r)=
\begin{cases}
4\lambda\pi r^2 e^{-(4/3)\lambda\pi r^3},&r>0\\
0,&\text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
$$

**My Answer So Far:**

We will work from the density, and imagine a sphere around a single
particle. Note that the distribution info for $Y$ is
\begin{align*}
p(y)&=\frac{(\lambda v)^ye^{-\lambda v}}{y!},\; y=0,1,2,\dots
\end{align*}
This is a discrete distribution. Now the density of particles is given by
$\rho=Y/v,$ measured in particles per length unit cubed. Now let's take a sphere
of radius $s$ and determine how many particles $n$ are in the sphere.
We would have
$$n=\rho\szdp{\frac{4\pi s^3}{3}}.$$
What we want to do now is shrink the sphere down until, on average, it has only
one particle in it. So we could set $n=1,\;s=r,$ and solve for $r:$
\begin{align*}
1&=\rho\szdp{\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}}\\
\frac{v}{Y}\cdot\frac{3}{4\pi}&=r^3\\
\sqrt[3]{\frac{3v}{4\pi Y}}&=r.
\end{align*}
Now here's the difficulty: $Y$ is discrete, but $r$ is continuous.

**My Question:** The method of distribution functions, the method of transformations, and the method of moment-generating functions either seem not to apply or don't look like they would work. (The target distribution is a Weibull, for which the mgf does not exist.) Is my approach sound? If so, what's the next step? If not, what's a better approach?

Comment: What you want to prove is not generally true. Notice, for instance, that your formula assigns positive probability even to distances that could exceed the diameter of $v$ (if $v$ is bounded). It could only be correct for asymptotically large $\lambda$ or when $v$ is most of $\mathbb{R}^3.$  Even then it appears to be at odds with https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/506096/919.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll skip this one, then.

Comment: The statement is missing a characterisation of the distribution of the $Y$ particles within the figure. Or need be stated for all figures of all possible volumes.